# angular.js , templatedata in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

```
var imageData = region[0].images;
alert(imageData.length);

templeteData = '<div class="col-sm-12 bootstrap-no-padding" >\
          <div  class="col-xs-4 col-sm-4 col-md-4 bootstrap-no-padding" style="height:250px">\
           <div class="borderAll black-carousel black-carousel-fixHW" uib-carousel no-pause="true" active="active" interval="5000" ng-if="imageData.length > 0"  no-wrap="noWrapSlides">\
              <div uib-slide ng-repeat="image in imageData" index="image.id" class="col-md-12">\
                <div class="image-thumbnail-content GridPositionRelative cursor-pointer">\
                  <image style="height:100%;top: 0px; width:100%" class="image fallback-image GridPositionRelative" ng-src="{{image.imageBase64StringFormat}}"/>\
                </div>\
              </div>\
            </div>\
          </div>\
          <div  class="col-xs-8 col-sm-8 col-md-8 bootstrap-no-padding" >' + regionDescription + '</div>\
          </div>'
```

in imageData is an array containing images as [0],[1].. etc
my problem is that the images are not getting displayed... I don't know if ng- does not work here.. can anyone help me

Answer (score 1):

`imageData` must be a scope variable of angular to bind to the template.

So instead of declaring as variable using var you should declare it like 
`$scope.imageData = region[0].images`
And make sure you have injected `$scope` if you are using controller

Comment: maybe also need to add : `$compile(templateData)(scope)` .

Comment: @LucienLu Yeah I think that will also required may be.

Comment: Yaa I had not made it as scope variable that's what was wrong.. thank you devang..